# React - error: package expo.modules.updates does not exist

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I ejected expo from my react project. But when I tried to run it on android I got an error saying

> error: package expo.modules.updates does not exist

And it actually comes up from `MainApplication.java` on my android folder.

```
import expo.modules.constants.ConstantsPackage;
import expo.modules.permissions.PermissionsPackage;
import expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemPackage;
import expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController;
```

I think expo not completely removed from my project. How do I resolve this issue? Thanks.

Edit : Here's my `package.json` maybe it can help.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.10.2",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^4.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "~0.61.5",
    "react-native-cardview": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-floating-labels": "^1.1.9",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-hide-show-password-input": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-image-header-scroll-view": "^0.10.3",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.9.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.9",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.3.13",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.8.12",
    "realm": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not know much about react but I have seen react-navigation package has been updated from 4x to 5x.

Answer (score 2):

Try to search in your android project for occurrences of expo.modules.*

I had a similar issue and found that there was a BasePackageList.java file that contained these references.
Deleting the file solved it.

Also you could take a look at this link [of a git commit removing expo from a RN project](https://git.etud.insa-toulouse.fr/saint-lo/application-amicale/commit/a4bbd841367ce2fc7609993c103e821ad466ca60)

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue, coming from this generated java file, deleting this file resolved the issue. BasePackageList.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.Package;

public class BasePackageList {
  public List<Package> getPackageList() {
    return Arrays.<Package>asList(
        new expo.modules.constants.ConstantsPackage(),
        new expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemPackage(),
        new expo.modules.imageloader.ImageLoaderPackage(),
        new expo.modules.location.LocationPackage()
    );
  }
}
```

Try search **expo.modules.*** in the codebase as the other post suggested will help.

Answer (score 0):

did you remove expo-updates from your package.json?

Comment: I did, i removed all expo related on `package.json`. I will include my `package.json` in my post if you want to see it.

Comment: well this is why you see the error then.. if you remove those packages then you need to also remove imports from MainApplication.. please note that you don’t need to actually do this, you can keep using all of the expo packages after ejecting, so you should probably keep them installed

Answer (score 0):

For me it was removing the following 3 lines in MainApplication.java:

```
import expo.modules.constants.ConstantsPackage;
import expo.modules.permissions.PermissionsPackage;
import expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemPackage;
```

After this my project installed on my phone again.